# How to setup nginx to proxy the requests to my web application?

Tags: nginx

How do I need to config my nginx to proxy requests to my application? If my (frontend) application runs on the 10.10.10.10:9999 address and I want to reach it in browser using the `myapplication.com`, what are the right configurations?

I have these at the moment but does not seem to work:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myapplication.com;

        location / {

            proxy_set_header    x-real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    x-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    host $host;
            proxy_pass          http://10.10.10.10:9999;
        }


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Did you look at access_logs of nginx?

Comment: Does not I have to setup some DNS because of the myapplication.com? If I try to open `myapplication.com` : "This site can't be reached. ... DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Comment: You can add the example dns into your hosts file [Edit Hosts File](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) or browse `http://localhost/` address

Comment: And what if 20 people would use this application? Can't really tell everyone to change their hosts files... Any idea?

Comment: This is for testing. Obviously, you should buy a domain address for publishing.

Comment: Right... And what if this application would be used at a company and only the employees would use the application? It would be some "in-company" software?

Comment: You can add basic authentication or ip whitelist for restricting users. Anyway, your website should have an authentication system for anonymous sign in.